# Escape special characters in SPARQL queries

Tags: java, sparql, jena, arq

I'm trying to query dpbedia to get the categories of some wikipedia articles using Jena and ARQ
For example:

```
select ?category { dbpedia:ARTICLE_NAME dcterms:subject ?category }
```

Here is an example of a working query
[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fcategory%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AFootball%20dcterms%3Asubject%20%3Fcategory%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The problem is when there are special characters in ARTICLE_NAME for example "Parma_F.C.", where there is "."

```
select ?category { dbpedia:Parma_F.C. dcterms:subject ?category }
```

[ERROR](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fcategory%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AParma_F.C.%20dcterms%3Asubject%20%3Fcategory%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

So, I would like to ask you if someone had a solution for that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The identifier `dbpedia:Parma_F.C.` is a so-called *prefixed name*, that is, an abbreviated form of a full URI. The full syntax rules for it are described in the [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#prefNames).

The problem is specifically the full stop at the end of the prefixed name. According to the SPARQL grammar, a prefixed name cannot end on a full stop unless it's escaped. The fix is simply to use a backslash:

```
 dbpedia:Parma_F.C\.
```

What you can also do as an alternative, is just write out the full URI. The `dbpedia` prefix maps to the `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` namespace, so the full URI in SPARQL would become:

```
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Parma_F.C.>
```

and the full query would become:

```
select ?category { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Parma_F.C.> dcterms:subject ?category }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to replace it with the full URI but it still doesn't work. May I ask you to show me how you did it exactly? Could you please paste a link for that through the dbpedia API? Thanks again

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Which characters need to be escaped in full URI syntax? I assume it is `<`, `>`, `\\`?